# Firebase realtime DB retrieving gives error in Rails App

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ruby-1.8.7

```
 result = firebase.get('chats/CONV000002').body.values


 result = {"-LEOiopfKHh82emTQBeS":{"arr_url":"https://test-vps2.s3.amazonaws.com/user_chats/IwnLnlERTxr/Test.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAI4OQXXUZDIJGDDXA&Expires=1528369920&Signature=0UUnptN1jaJhfLCHpD2z%2BJHWnXo%3D","chat_date":"2018-06-07T10:12:00+00:00","employee_id":696,"f_name":"Test.pdf","guardian_id":"3710","message":"11","sender":"employee"},"-LEOirijIvapxuQgzRZZ":{"arr_url":"","chat_date":"2018-06-07T10:12:12+00:00","employee_id":696,"f_name":"","guardian_id":"3710","message":"how are you ?","sender":"employee"},"-LEOr8zBkjzLiZfl2ppq":{"arr_url":"","chat_date":"2018-06-07T13:48:24+03:00","employee_id":696,"f_name":"","guardian_id":"3167","message":"one","sender":"employee"},"-LEOrGr5nAuDEx3-VzyZ":{"arr_url":"","chat_date":"2018-06-07T13:48:56+03:00","employee_id":696,"f_name":"","guardian_id":"3167","message":"dsdsdsdsdsdsdsd","sender":"employee"}}
```

After Including Order By and Limit below error triggered.

```
firebase.get('chats/CONV000002', :orderBy => 'chat_date', :limitToFirst => 1).body.values
 Error:  ["orderBy must be a valid JSON encoded path"]
```

Comment: Appreciate your response

Comment: Looks like in your data it is `chat_date`, not `chart_date`. Is this a typo (here or somewhere else)?

Comment: yes @Andre, which i have corrected still the same error

Comment: Can you try putting `chat_date` in double quotes like this: `' "chat_date" '` (extra spaces added to make it more clear) ([source of this possible solution](https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php/issues/58))